# Problem to run website in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have downloaded a web site project and its an ASP.NET web site use for sending SMS.

I am using Windows 7. I've configured IIS 7.5 with 3.5 .NET Framework. After configuring IIS 7.5 when I use IIS Manager with command (`inetmgr`) to add virtual directory and website with the path in my computer `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/web` (web is virtual directory ) I just paste all the file and folder of web site in virtual directory and then add web site with physical path: `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/web` for web site all work fine, but when I run (browse) webpage I get an error:

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Answer (score 4):

This simply means your virtual-directory has directory-listing disabled and no default page - you could either:

- Navigate to a certain page directly
- Enable Directory-Listing
- Set a default page for the current virtual-directory

Comment: you can download web site from direct link of web site given below and try to run in your computer thanks for answering  http://www.fullinterview.com/forum1/attachment.php?aid=3975